# how to convert a string into a variable name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If

```
   FRUIT_VAR_NAME = '/abc/{}' 
   VEGETABLE_VAR_NAME = '/bcd/{}'
   def mathod(prefix):   
      path = '{}_VAR_NAME'.format(prefix)   
      value_path = path.format('mno')   
      print(value_path)
```

How to get the answer as /abc/mno when prefix is FRUIT_VAR_NAME and /bcd/mno
when prefix = VEGETABLE_VAR_NAME

Comment: Don't. Use a dict instead.

Comment: Use the exec() function.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead. You were mistakingly putting the string `'/abc/{}'` inside of the braces of `'{}_VAR_NAME'`

```py
FRUIT_VAR_NAME = '/abc/{}' 
VEGETABLE_VAR_NAME = '/bcd/{}'

def mathod(prefix):   
    value_path = prefix.format('mno')   
    print(value_path)
```